# How to select certain colums in yii CActive record?

Tags: php, yii

I want to get all rows , certain columns using CActive record

I heard about findAll(); but it returns all rows, colums

```
$models = Users::model()->findAll();
```

How to get certain columns for example, only username, password for all users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do with `CDbCriteria`

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 't.username, t.password '; // select fields which you want in output
$models = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: intha questiona paarunga na http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918336/delete-verb-is-not-working-in-yii-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result in the form of array try this

```
$records= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('username,password')
                    ->from('users')
                    ->queryAll();
```

If as an object then **kumar_v** has already given an answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use as usual `sql` query but getting so would not be in yii standard

So get `findAll()` and get the data that you want. that is proposed and best.

Answer (score 0):

the **Kumar_v** 's answer is completely correct, but if you want only username and password (or any **two** fields),

you can also use `CHtml::listData()` function like this :

```
 $users=CHtml::listData(Users::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'*condition*',
'limit'='*limit*')),"username", "password");
```

the $users is an array like this :

```
$users = array(
'username1'=>'password1',
'username2'=>'password2',
.
.
.

);
```

and of course you can access to a username's password simply by `$users['username1']`