# DELETE verb is not working in Yii Rest Api?

Tags: php, rest, yii

When try to delete a record using Yii Rest api

HTTP DELETE mothod is not working

my url routing is

```
array('users/list', 'pattern'=>'users/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
```

when i request like

```
http://localhost/api/users/delete?id=1
```

in method DELETE in rest client

it says `there is no method like delete`

so i created an action like the following

```
public function actionDelete()
    {


        switch($_GET['action'])
        {
        case 'delete': // {{{
                $id = $_GET['id'];
                $this->DeleteUser($id);
                break; // }}}
            default:
                    break;
        }
}
```

Now it says undefined index : model

My understanding is if we use HTTP DELETE method we should have an action called actionDelete right?

How to fix this ?

Comment: Are you using an extension or your own API?

Comment: have you check this tutorial? -- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

verb => 'DELETE' means that the request method is delete.

You should be able to call your api with the following javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php/api/users/1',
    type: 'DELETE',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
      alert('Deleted');
    },
    error: function(result) {
      alert('Could not delete!');
    }
});
```

Do you have the standard filters active? If yes, you should remove "postOnly + delete".

```
/**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
    );
}
```